# running jupyter lab on a remote port 80

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm in constrained corporate environment that I access through a very slow vpn from my local machine.

I'm writing a lot of database load/unload things that are like 50x faster if I run them from a box in aws.  So I can successfully create a box, rdp into it, pip install jupyterlab, use the browser inside the RDP and it all works fine.

However, then I'm working through an RDP and can't access clipboard or all the other tools installed on my machine, or the data on my machine, so I'm constantly having to transfer things through to this compute box.

Firewall wise the only ports open on the remote box are 80, 443 and 3389.

so - I thought - I'll just run jupyter-lab on the remote box on port 80 - use it from the browser on my local machine, and I will get the best of both worlds - the stuff will run fast on the remote box, but I can edit it from my main box.

Except that I can't for the life of me get it to work, and I don't even understand why.   I put it on port 80, and can access it locally fine from inside RDP - but remotely it's like it's not even there.   When I google - I either find instructions for setting up jupyter *notebook*  remotely like this - or for setting up jupyter-lab using ssh - but I want lab not notebook - and ssh isn't even close to being an option.

**Is it possible to run jupyter-lab on port 80 on machine A and then access it from a browser on machine B?   and if so - how do I do it?**

Comment: Can you run Wireshark/tcpdump to check where are the packets being dropped? I suspect the firewall may be dropping the packets (although you've stated that ports are open in the firewall).

Comment: you need to do something called port forwarding.

Comment: first create an ssh terminal into the other machine. then run this command: `ssh -CNL <hostname> localhost:80:localhost:80`. after opening localhost:80 on your browser you should see jupyter load up. I've done this before using google colab.

Comment: I mentioned that using ssh isn't an option - I have rdp - ssh port isn't open - and these are windows boxes

Comment: lab and notebook are basically using the same server so you should be able to use instructions for one to set up to other, but you might need to update them to account for migration to jupyter_server see https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html#migrate-from-notebook in JupyterLab 3.0. I only used ssh hops which always worked great but cannot help with RDP.